# The system cannot find the path specified in JAR

Tags: java, file, audio, jar, path

I'm trying to play an audio file. In my IDE (intellij) that works completely fine, but when running in a JAR, I get the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\soni801\Documents\Redsea Productions\The Great X Wars\alpha-0.0.7.1.jar\audio\click.au (The system cannot find the path specified)`

The file's location inside the JAR is `audio/click.au`, and the JAR is located at `D:\soni801\Documents\Redsea Productions\The Great X Wars\alpha-0.0.7.1.jar` which afaik should make the absolute path `D:\soni801\Documents\Redsea Productions\The Great X Wars\alpha-0.0.7.1.jar\audio\click.au`, however the system can't find a file at this location? What's happening here?

This is the code in my `AudioPlayer.java` file:

```java
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath() /*+ "/res"*/ + filePath).getAbsoluteFile());

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(inputStream);
```

Alternatively, you can find the entire file, as well as the rest of the project, on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/soni801/xwars/blob/master/src/com/xwars/main/AudioPlayer.java)

All help is appreciated.

*I am aware that this might be a duplicate of other questions, but unfortunately other solutions didn't solve my problem*

*If the question is unclear, comment any improvements I could make, and I will edit the question*

Comment: Now getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` method is overloaded and can accept a `File`, a `URL` or an `InputStream` as an argument. Of these, `URL` is usually the best choice.

It's advantage over `File` is that a `URL` can address a file within a jar, which a `File` cannot do.

It's advantage over `InputStream` is that additional conditions are imposed: the audio file must support `mark` and `reset` methods. My experience with audio files is that it's kind of hit or miss as to whether this will be possible or not. I confess I don't know the specifics as to why.

To obtain a URL from your jar, the simplest form it perhaps the following:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("yourAudioFileName");
```

This assumes that the audio resource is in the same package as the class "this". Subfolders of the package can be addressed as well, this way. But I don't think the symbol "../" can be counted on to obtain a resource from a parent folder.

Alternatively, instead of 'this' you can specify a class in the package or parent package of the audio resource. Also, you can prefix the address with a "/". In this last case, e.g., `this.getClass().getResource("/yourAudioFileName")`, the root source folder of the project is the starting point for the address rather than the package holding 'this'.